# Use $lte for datetime querying is not working

Tags: mongodb

I want to query data by using datetime that less than 15:00 in 2016-01-14 but it is not working.

Here is my example collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5697528237b79c198c94ad1a"),
    "actionName" : "touchMove",
    "timeStamp" : ISODate("2016-01-14T14:47:13.596Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5697528237b79c198c94ad16"),
    "actionName" : "touchDown",
    "timeStamp" : ISODate("2016-01-14T14:47:13.597Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5697528237b79c198c94ad1e"),
    "actionName" : "touchMove",
    "timeStamp" : ISODate("2016-01-14T16:01:49.620Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5697528237b79c198c94ad1b"),
    "actionName" : "touchDown",
    "timeStamp" : ISODate("2016-01-14T16:01:50.010Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5697528237b79c198c94ad17"),
    "actionName" : "touchMove",
    "timeStamp" : ISODate("2016-01-14T16:01:49.630Z")
}
```

And here is my query code

```
db.getCollection('app1_touchpoint').find({
 'timeStamp' : {'$lte':new Date(2016, 01, 14, 15, 00)}
})
```

When I do query, the data that have a 'timeStamp' more than 2016-01-14 15:00 are shown in the result too. Actually all data are shown. 
Is anyone able to give me some advice as to how I should do this query in the right way? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The date you are adding to your query is a local date by default in c#. But - dates in mongo are utc by default.

You have a couple of options.

1. **Move** to a place that's on the other side of the utc line. This will solve your problem for lte, but may create a problem for gte.
2. **Use DateTimeKind.Utc** and set that date type to utc before you use it to query.

For Example

If I were going to do that with your sample data, I'd do it this way:

```
var dt = DateTime.SpecifyKind(new Date(2016, 01, 14, 15, 0, 0), DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
db.getCollection('app1_touchpoint').find({
 'timeStamp' : {'$lte':dt}
});
```

I assume the goal is to query the dates in your db as they sit (not to query them AFTER you convert those dates to your timezone).  This will accomplish that goal.

Comment: It would be pleasure if you show me some example. Thank you.